# understanding how onehotencoder works - why do i get mutliple ones in ohe column?

Tags: scikit-learn, pipeline, categorical-data, sklearn-pandas, one-hot-encoding

I am using sklearn pipelines to perform one-hot encoding:

```
preprocess = make_column_transformer(
    (MinMaxScaler(),numeric_cols),
    (OneHotEncoder(),['country'])
    )

param_grid =    { 
                  'xgbclassifier__learning_rate': [0.01,0.005,0.001],
                 
                  }

model = make_pipeline(preprocess,XGBClassifier())

# Initialize Grid Search Modelg
model = GridSearchCV(model,param_grid = param_grid,scoring = 'roc_auc',
                                 verbose= 1,iid= True,
                                     refit = True,cv  = 3)
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

To see then how the countries are one hot encoded I get the following ( I know there are two)

```
pd.DataFrame(preprocess.fit_transform(X_test))
```

The result of this is:

[image]

A few questions:

- now correct me if wrong but in one hot encoding I thought it was a series of all 0's and just ONE number 1. why do I get several ones in one column
- when I do model.predict(x_test) it applies the trasnformations as defined in the piepline fom training?
- how do I retrieve the feature names when I call fit_transform?

Comment: (1) one `1` per row (2) yes (3) you need to access `OHE` transformer and check `vocabulary_` attribute

Comment: where is this in the documentation i cannot find it (the vocabulary attribute?)

Comment: It is `categories_` attribute for fitted `OHE`. Sorry for misleading you. The docs are [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)

Comment: ok so this is to get the features after i call fit_transform. i'm sorry i don't understand what you mean in (1), is it true you only need one 1 per vector for a catgory because in the docs you shared just now if you scroll to bottom the ohe vectors have more than one 1

Comment: to add i meant when i call fit_transform(X_test) how do i get the feature names of all??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help you better understand (1), i.e. how `OHE` works.

Suppose you have 1 column with categorical data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"categorical": ["a","b","a"]})
print(df)
  categorical
0           a
1           b
2           a
```

Then you'll get one `1` per row (this will always be true for one column categorical data), but not necessarily on a per column basis:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ohe = OneHotEncoder()
ohe.fit(df)
ohe_out = ohe.transform(df).todense()
# ohe_df = pd.DataFrame(ohe_out, columns=ohe.get_feature_names(df.columns))
ohe_df = pd.DataFrame(ohe_out, columns=ohe.get_feature_names(["categorical"]))
print(ohe_df)
   categorical_a  categorical_b
0            1.0            0.0
1            0.0            1.0
2            1.0            0.0
```

Should you add more data columns, e.g. a numerical column, this will hold true on a per column basis, but not for the whole row anymore:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"categorical":["a","b","a"],"nums":[0,1,0]})
print(df)
  categorical  nums
0           a     0
1           b     1
2           a     0
```

---

```
ohe.fit(df)
ohe_out = ohe.transform(df).todense()
# ohe_df = pd.DataFrame(ohe_out, columns=ohe.get_feature_names(df.columns))
ohe_df = pd.DataFrame(ohe_out, columns=ohe.get_feature_names(["categorical","nums"]))
print(ohe_df)
   categorical_a  categorical_b  nums_0  nums_1
0            1.0            0.0     1.0     0.0
1            0.0            1.0     0.0     1.0
2            1.0            0.0     1.0     0.0
```